# NetBeans doesn't recognize imported class

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been working for a couple of weeks and NetBeans hasn't done anything like this before: it doesn't recognize an import. I've tried some workarounds but I can't get past this.
To better understand what's going on here are some screenshots:
[image: not qualified name]
The respective import has a warning as it's unused;
With qualified name:
[image: qualified name]

I've tried fully qualified with the same effect. I chose the name from the very suggestion list. any method I pick is unrecognized. 
[image: fully qualified and suggested name]

I can tell this is a NetBeans bug but what can I do to go on with my project? I've tried advices on other answers like deleting the cache, deleting the roaming\7.4 contents even reinstalling. I've worked on NetBeans 7.4; uninstalled and replaced it with NetBeans 8.0, all for nothing.
And aren't *identical* words supposed to be visually cued by the yellowish color?
[image: identical?]

Comment: Have you added the library to your project?

Comment: Yes, glGenBuffers works just fine, see the line above the problematic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question. Try these link:
[[Organize Imports] missing for Use Fully Qualified Names](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236939)

Comment: IF it's a bug then it doesn't depend on whether the name is fully/not qualified.

Comment: Commonly in Eclipse causes these problem due to not changing the perspective of project which is opened. I don't know about netbeans that is this option exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the version of the library that you added to your project does not contain that particular class. You could also try to import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*; (not a good practice) and see what happens.